# Can you read different tasks of srun into Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, slurm

When running srun, the flag "-n" generally specifies how many tasks you want per node. Is there a way to read the different task IDs into python. For example, define a basic python file *test.py*:

```
#test.py

#somehow read the task ID as taskID
taskID = ...

print('task ID: ' + str(taskID))
```

Now, is there some way to define *taskID* so that

`srun -n2 python3 test.py` will print the following:

```
task ID 0
task ID 1
```

I know this can be done with other parallel frameworks like MPI as you can define each task's rank, but was wondering if this can be done by only using slurm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the SLURM-jobID as an input argument to python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441887/how-to-pass-the-slurm-jobid-as-an-input-argument-to-python) .. Never used srun but this seemed close?

Comment: @JeffUK I looked at that link before posting my question. At least to my understanding, jobID is different than what I am looking for. For my example above, jobID would return the ID of the entire slurm submission "srun -n2 python3 test.py", not the individual tasks within the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SLURM_PROCID` environment variable should give what you want:

```
#test.py
import os
#somehow read the task ID as taskID
taskID = os.environ["SLURM_PROCID"]

print('task ID: ' + str(taskID))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work. Is there some manual page where this information could be found? Another question I have is if there is some way to find the total number of tasks in python.

Comment: The information can be found here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_SLURM_PROCID

Comment: As for your second question, the information is in `SLURM_NPROCS`.